# What does "Allow self relations" on Asset fields mean?

Tags: assets, localization, plugin-supertable

In the Advanced section of an Asset Field configuration, there is the "Allow self relations" checkbox. What does this do?

I've noticed that when I have the Propagation Method of *the field* set to "Save blocks to other sites with the same language" *and* I have a SuperTable with an Assets field, I need this option to be enabled on the Asset in order for my asset content to propagate if I choose to "Add a site" an Entry (the Section's Propagation Method is set to to "Let each entry choose which sites it should be saved to").

[image]

Comment: I misdiagnosed the issue I was having, "Allow self relations" was not related to the propagation issues I was having.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need it checked in your exact scenario but this was added in 3.4.21. Information on it here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#3421---2020-05-28 and here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6113)

Comment: Yeah, it turns out i misdiagnosed the issue I was having.  It was an issue with Super Table and custom propagation.  I made this PR with a fix that worked for me: https://github.com/verbb/super-table/pull/430.

Thanks for the support though!